# track shipment with shippo

Tags: curl, shippo

I am trying to integrate shippo API to track my shipment informationa and here is the CURL request i am sending

```
curl https://api.goshippo.com/v1/tracks/ -H "Authorization: ShippoToken <TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"tracking_number":"<TRACKING_NUMBER>"}
```

But i am send a response as below

```
{"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}
```

Can any one tell me as to what could be going wrong.

Comment: The error message is quite clear on what's going wrong.

Comment: Hello Alec, yes i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Here is how is fixed this

curl -H "Authorization: ShippoToken " -H "Content-Type: application/json' {"carrier":"","tracking_number":""}' https://api.goshippo.com/v1/tracks/